# Test/Development WordPress websites in Azure

Tags: wordpress, azure, azure-web-app-service

I am looking to stand-up a development/test WordPress website in Azure alongside our production site and am looking for any best practices I can find.

The idea is to keep the environments the same having both sites on the Azure PaaS but having different URL's to be able to access them. And having the databases be separate (to ensure we don't mess up anything in production)

Example...

Production -- http://companywebsite.com

Development -- http://test.companywebsite.com

Has anyone attempted something like this before? It would be fairly simple if the development was being done locally but we need multiple (non-developer) users to be able to access the WordPress admin panel on the test site and be able to install plugins and such to test.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

have you tried deployment slot?

> When you deploy your web app to App Service, you can deploy to a
>   separate deployment slot instead of the default production slot when
>   running in the Standard or Premium App Service plan mode.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-staged-publishing/

**Update:**

Seems like you can also config wordpress to aware of staging environment.

http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-create-staging-environment-for-a-wordpress-site/

Comment: I have been reading about the deployment slot but I was under the impression that it was for long-term testing. The organization doesn't have a repository to push from so this would be something like a manual process each time it needs updated.

Backup production site, restore data to test site to use.

Comment: @Brandon even if you do not have a repository, you can still use slot for your manual process. the good part about slot is it give you an environment for testing, and once you feel good about it, you can just swap it with production slot. and you can keep their setting separate, e.g database connection string, then when you are on staging slot you are using your test database. Hope this information will help.

Comment: @Xiomin it does thank you! And I've used the deployment slot but as soon as I try to login to the test wordpress admin panel, it shoots me over to the production admin panel. I can't figure out a way to make those changes before doing the restore without breaking the production site.

Comment: @Brandon even you are not using a repository, take a look at this article to see if it helps. http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-create-staging-environment-for-a-wordpress-site/ seems like there is some configuration you can do in wordpress to let it know you have a stagging enviroment.

Comment: That article is exactly what I was looking for. Amazing my google searching never turned it up. Thanks again!

Comment: nice! glad you find what you want.